# Applying CSS to a MediaWiki site

Tags: mediawiki

I am a Wikipedia editor, and I find that I can adjust the appearance of what I see by applying CSS in Preferences / Appearance.

For the fun of it I have set up a MediaWiki site on my shared hosted site, and I find that I don't have the same options in Preferences / Appearance.  To be specific, on Wikipedia I see that I can do various things with regard to the Vector skin:

```
Vector (default | Preview | Custom CSS | Custom JavaScript)
```

I can choose Custom CSS and add "font-size: 1.1em;" to the Body tag and make things a bit larger for my older eyes.  However, in my installation my skins are like this:

```
Vector (default | Preview)
```

I have only just set this site up a few days ago, and there's no content to speak of yet, and I have yet to learn how to do all the things I need to know, but I was surprised I couldn't set custom CSS!  Is there some setting somewhere that I, as the Boss, can make custom CSS available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I tracked it down myself -- fun and games!

Anyway, this turns out to one of oodles of settings that are set in localsettings.php.  I found it in the manual, believe it or not.  You know, as in RTFM?

By default, this setting is false.  Put it in local settings and make it true.

```
$wgAllowUserCss = true;
```

See the manual, [HERE](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowUserCss).